# apache2 point folder to subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, virtualhost, subdomain, proxypass

I need to point **domain.com/chat** to **chat.domain.com**. So, when I access **domain.com/chat** I want to see the same thing as when I access **chat.domain.com**.

My virtualhost for this looks like below. As you can see I have tried doing it with proxypass, but I think I am doing something wrong.

```
 ServerAdmin info@domain.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com
 ServerName domain.com

 ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/domain.com-error_log
 CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domain.com-access_log combined


 ProxyRequests Off
 ProxyPreserveHost On

 <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
 </Proxy>

 ProxyPass /chat http://chat.domain.com/chat
 ProxyPassReverse /chat http://chat.domain.com/chat

 <Location /chat>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
 </Location>

 <Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
 </Location>

  <Directory /var/www/domain.com>
      Options FollowSymLinks 
      AllowOverride All
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: *I have tried doing it with proxypass, but I think I am doing something wrong* : The ProxyPass directive seems OK if chat resides in `chat.example.com/chat` so what **evidence** do you have that things are not working as intended or expected?

Comment: chat resides in `chat.example.com/`.  `example.com` is running a Wordpress website. So, the evidence is that when I access `example.com/chat`it shows me the WP website with a Page Not Found.

Comment: Then  for starters try to set your proxy directive to the correct location: `ProxyPass /chat http://chat.example.com/`